# Display image in WPF from database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, image, exception

I have the following database:
[image]
and I would like to display all employees and their pictures in a listbox. Whenever I run my code, I receive an System.InvalidOperationException at this part of the code:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var list = db.Employees;
        list.Load();
        liemp.ItemsSource = list.Local.OrderBy(l => l.LastName);
    }
```

This is my WPF code:

```
<Window x:Class="NorthwindWPF.employeeList"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NorthwindWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="employeeList" Height="350" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="liemp"
            DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"
            SelectedValuePath="EmployeeID">
            <Image Source="{Binding PhotoPath}" />
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is my class code:

```
namespace NorthwindWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for employeeList.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class employeeList : Window
    {

        NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();

        public employeeList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var list = db.Employees;
            list.Load();
            liemp.ItemsSource = list.Local.OrderBy(l => l.LastName);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have directly added a single `Image` item to the ListBox.

```
<ListBox ...>
    <Image Source="{Binding PhotoPath}" /> <!-- here -->
</ListBox>
```

Subsequently setting the ListBox's `ItemsSource` will then fail with an `InvalidOperationException`.

Instead of setting the ListBox's `DisplayMemberPath` property, you should define its `ItemTemplate` like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="liemp" SelectedValuePath="EmployeeID">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding PhotoPath}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: For some reason the program freezes and I looked at the image path now and I guess they are invalid: http://accweb/emmployees/davolio.bmp

Comment: Should he not use `ObservableCollection` as the `DataSource` for the `liemp`?

Comment: @Everyone For what reason? Apparently the ItemsSource property is set once to a fixed collection. Besides that, there is no `DataSource` here.

Comment: @Michael You may write a Binding Converter that converts from a relative path to ImageSource.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the answer.